# How reply to multiple incoming emails with the same body

Tags: linux, email, script, automation, shell-script

I want to be able to reply to multiple emails with the same body. In this scenario the reply-to field is different, and so is the original body of the email.
The only thing that stays the same would be my reply.

I have read about the Mozilla templates, but I can not see how to dynamically auto populate the reply-to field as well as the original content.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Mozilla Thunderbird

I am posting here since this may be done best with an script.
I think I'll have to write a script to accomplish something like this. Although I have to say, I would be surprised if someone has not implemented a similar functionality already.

The one obstacle I see in creating a script for this, would be to configure the mail settings into Ubuntu somewhere.

Not a huge task, but I think it would have to be done.

I was a big fan of Pico, but I have not looked into what replaced it and if it is a robust email client.

So I like to know if my existing setup allows me to do something like this, and if not, what are the best tools and configuration to add to get this functionality please.

Comment: If you fetch your email properly to the Ubuntu system and don't just use Thunderbird to read it online, you can use `procmail` to automatically react on incoming mail based on various criteria, and `formail` to modify headers. The `procmail` documentation has examples on how to set this up.